# Delegate a method call, to another method

Tags: c#, methods

I am not sure if what I am looking for is even possible, but I wonder if there is a way to delegate a method, when it is called, to another method. Let's say I have a declared object Receiver with a public method OnReceived(string param), inside a class ReceiverMiddleMan. When this method is called on Receiver, I would like to pass the parameters of this method to a method OnReceivedInMiddleMan somehow, not necessarily in the way as is shown in the code. Why? Because I would like to know if the data in Receiver.OnReceived can be got directly, without for instance inheriting from Receiver to access the method. The Receiver class, used here as an example, is in real life a Third party library which I cannot modify with events and such. The only access I have is the public method.

```
class Receiver
{
    public void OnReceived(string param)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class ReceiverMiddleMan
{
    Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
    Listen(receiver.OnReceived);

    public void Listen(Method method)
    {
        OnReceivedInMiddleMan(method.param);
    }

    public void OnReceivedInMiddleMan(string param)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could create an `event` in your `Receiver` class and subscribe to it in `ReceiverMiddleMan` somewhere

Comment: Read about events and delegates.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a DI container which returns a wrapper around the instances being requested/injected and can log the call (or whatever you want to do) before forwarding on to the final recipient.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the Receiver class, used here as an example, is in real life a Third party library which I cannot modify with events and such. The only access I have is the public method.

Comment: Perhaps the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would be of use.

Comment: `public void Listen(Action<string> onReceived) { ...` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/delegates-strongly-typed

Comment: For me it sounds like you want to do testing. If so, take a look into Mocks.